# Php regular expression to match a div

Tags: php, preg-match-all

This is mycode

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Joomlacoders
 * @copyright 2010
 */
    $url="http://urlchecker.net/html/demo.html";

    $innerHtml=file_get_contents($url);

    //echo $innerHtml;
    preg_match_all("{\<div id='news-id-.*d'\>(.*)\</div\>}",$innerHtml,$matches);

          //<div id='news-id-160346'>            

    var_dump($matches);

?>
```

I want find all content in div id='news-id-160346'. Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use an HTML parser. **NOT** regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

The problem with regular expressions is that they cannot match nested structures. Assuming your regex must match a single `<div>` and its closing tag, there is no way to correctly match this input:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        Foo
    </div>
</div>
<div id="c">
    Bar
</div>
```

Because if your regular expression is greedy, it will match the two uppermost divs, and if it's ungreedy, it will not match the correct end tag.

Therefore, you should use an HTML parser. With PHP, [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) or [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) each do a fairly good job. (You may "safely" ignore the warnings it generates: they're only markup errors, and the generated `DOMDocument` object should be pretty much okay.)

Since the PHP getElementById is a pain to get to work, you can use DOMXpath for the same purpose:

```
<?php

$url = "http://urlchecker.net/html/demo.html";

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$myNews = $xpath->query('//@id="news-id-160346"')->item(0);

?>
```

Comment: Hello I had try all answer but not successful

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Unexpected end tag : a in http://urlchecker.net/html/demo.html, line: 26 in /home/urlcheck/public_html/html/test.php on line 10

Comment: @Thoman: it's actually been successful. loadHTMLFile simply tells you the problems it encountered while parsing. You can shut it up with the `@` operator: `@$d->loadHTMLFile($url);`

Comment: I try it but this code don't matches all content in id='news-id-160346'

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser as others suggested.

Or try this regex:

```
preg_match_all("#<div [^>]*id=['\"]news-id-\\d+['\"](.*?)</div>#", $innerHtml, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Check the output of the `print_r` statement **to understand why regex is not considered as the right tool** for parsing html.

Comment: @Thoman Read my last line again. It won't match - that is the whole point - it can't be fixed.